# How does Ubuntu's indexation work on a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, indexing

It's been almost one year since I posted that question on Unix & Linux. It still has no answer and only a little amount of views so I'm posting it here...

I have read on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles the following sentence:

> Thankfully my computer indexes all my files every night while I sleep
>   and I can search just the index, which will take only a few seconds,
>   even on as an expansive a filesystem as mine.

And I was just wondering how does it work on a virtual machine? Does it occur even though the VM and/or the host are powered off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vast majority of programs make no distinction between running on a physical computer or a virtual machine. When a physical or virtual computer is powered off it is not powered on. It does not run programs. If the host is powered off then all virtual machines in it are also powered off. In particular, your reference points to the package [`locate`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/locate), which includes two utilties: [`updatedb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/updatedb.8.html), which manages a database of file names and is typically run nightly by [`cron`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/cron.8.html), and [`locate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man1/locate.findutils.1.html) which uses that database to find files.

If you want your computer to run programs at night then you should keep it powered on during the night, obviously.

Read about `cron` and [`anacron`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/anacron.8.html) and the difference between them to learn how to set up a job which runs periodically on a computer which is not powered on continuously.

Comment: Actually the package is mlocate by default, but you can install locate and use `update-alternatives` to configure symbolic links `locate` and `updatedb` to use its executables, instead.